# Among us crewmate and imposter generator not working

Tags: ruby, random, generator

What I am trying to do is have a random generator generate 9 cremates and 1 impostor but what happens when it generates them is one of the cremates isn't generated and its just a blank space in between the other string values when I display the values on cmd so idk why it doesn't but I feel it may be to do with the player so there is 10 crews and 1 impostor.

```
impgen = rand (1..10)
deadgen = rand (1..9)
if impgen == 2
  impot = 'Red'
elsif impgen == 3 
  impot = 'Orange'
elsif impgen == 4 
  impot = 'Yellow'
elsif impgen == 5
  impot = 'Green'
end
if impgen == 6
  impot = 'Dark Green'
elsif impgen == 7
  impot = 'Blue'
elsif impgen == 8
  impot = 'Purple'
elsif impgen == 9
  impot = 'Black'
elsif impgen == 10
  impot = 'Cyan'
end
if impgen != 2
  crew1 = 'Red'
if impgen != 3
  crew2 = 'Orange'
end
if impgen != 4
  crew3 = 'Yellow'
if impgen != 5
  crew4 = 'Green'
end
if impgen != 6
  crew5 = 'Dark Green'
if impgen != 7 
  crew6 = 'Blue'
end
if impgen != 8
  crew7 = 'Purple'
if impgen != 9
  crew8 = 'Black'
end
if impgen != 10
  crew9 = 'Cyan'
end
end
end
end
end
puts "Enter Name"
un = gets.chomp
puts "Ok " + un + " let's play Among Us"
sleep (1)
if impgen == 1
  puts "You are an imposter!"
else impgen
  puts "You are a crewmate there is 1 imposter among us!"
  sleep (1.5)
  puts "The other players are Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Dark Green, Blue, Purple, Black, and Cyan you are Lime"
  sleep (4)
  puts impot
  puts crew1
  puts crew2
  puts crew3
  puts crew4
  puts crew5
  puts crew6
  puts crew7
  puts crew8
  puts crew9
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest issue becomes apparent when you indent your code:

```
if impgen != 2
  crew1 = 'Red'
  if impgen != 3
    crew2 = 'Orange'
  end
  if impgen != 4
    crew3 = 'Yellow'
    if impgen != 5
      crew4 = 'Green'
    end
    if impgen != 6
      crew5 = 'Dark Green'
      if impgen != 7 
        crew6 = 'Blue'
      end
      if impgen != 8
        crew7 = 'Purple'
        if impgen != 9
          crew8 = 'Black'
        end
        if impgen != 10
          crew9 = 'Cyan'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

There is a major bug here. For example, if `impgen == 2`, then none of the following code will get executed, and none of the crew variables will be assigned. You probably don't want to use nested if statements here, but instead do something like this:

```
if impgen != 2
  crew1 = 'Red'
end
if impgen != 3
  crew2 = 'Orange'
end
if impgen != 4
  crew3 = 'Yellow'
end
if impgen != 5
  crew4 = 'Green'
end
if impgen != 6
  crew5 = 'Dark Green'
end
if impgen != 7 
  crew6 = 'Blue'
end
if impgen != 8
  crew7 = 'Purple'
end
if impgen != 9
  crew8 = 'Black'
end
if impgen != 10
  crew9 = 'Cyan'
end
```

If you just make this change, you'll see that there is a consistent empty line that appears in the output. The reasoning is pretty clear, the imposter's crew member variable isn't getting assigned when `impgen` is a certain value. For example, if `impgen` is 2, `impgen != 2` evaluates to false, and `crew1 = 'Red'` doesn't get executed.

If this behavior is undesirable, you can just drop the if statements completely:

```
crew1 = 'Red'
crew2 = 'Orange'
crew3 = 'Yellow'
crew4 = 'Green'
crew5 = 'Dark Green'
crew6 = 'Blue'
crew7 = 'Purple'
crew8 = 'Black'
crew9 = 'Cyan'
```

**Edit:**
You may want to consider refactoring this code. I'm not sure how you plan to use your crew mate variables, but it might be easier to keep track of each member in an array:

```
crew_members = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Dark Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Black", "Cyan"]
player = crew_members.sample
imposter = crew_members.sample

puts "Enter Name"
un = gets.chomp
puts "Ok " + un + " let's play Among Us"
sleep (1)
if player == imposter
  puts "You are an imposter!"
else
  puts "You are a crewmate there is 1 imposter among us!"
  sleep (1.5)
  puts "The other players are #{(crew_members - [player]).join(", ")} you are #{player}"
end
```